# What is the minimal polynomial of A?.

Tags: linear-algebra

let$ A = \begin{bmatrix}2& −2& −4\\−1 &3& 4\\1 &−2 &-3\end{bmatrix}$

What is the minimal polynomial of A?

i find the eigenvalue of A that is $\lambda = 1, 0$

minimal polynomial  of A =  $(\lambda -1 )\lambda$

EDits : minimal polynomial  of A =  $(\lambda -1 )^2\lambda$

Is  it true ????

see my edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the fact that the eigenvalues if $A$ are $0$ and $1$ is *not* enough to prove that its minimal polynomial is $\lambda(\lambda-1)$. For instance, the minimal polynomial of\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}is $\lambda(\lambda-1)^2$.

However, since$$\bigl((4,0,1),(2,1,0),(1,-1,1)\bigr)$$is an ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since its first two vectors are eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$ and since the third one is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$, $A$ is similar to$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$and therefore, yes, its minimal polynomial is $\lambda(\lambda-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial has the property that when you substitute the matrix for the variable, you get zero.  Is it the case that $(A - I)A = 0$?

This criterion is not strong enough to show you are done.  You also have to show that no divisor of a polynomial giving you zero is a polynomial that gives you zero.  (Much as the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, both of which give zero when the matrix is substituted for the variable.)